# React router redirect with static parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

Actually pretty simple what I am trying to do but I guess not simple enough. I am trying to redirect from one page to another while passing a static parameter.

Example:

`/learn => / with ?source=ABC123`

I'm trying to use the following code to do it:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
  <Redirect from="/learn" to="/?source=ABC123" />
</Route>
```

The redirect works, however, the HomePage component doesn't actually get shown until you refresh the page. Any ideas on how to handle this?

I am using `"react-router": "3.0.1",` version.

Comment: what is the version of react router you are using?

Comment: @palsrealm Added it to initial question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a current working solution. As for it being 'best practice' or not, it is a current 'bandaid' fix for my situation.

I'm performing the redirect from `react-router`

```
<Redirect from="/learn" to="/?source=CA3U"/>
```

Then I'm just setting an actual route to those parameters while associating the `HomePage` component to that route:

```
<Route path="/?source=CA3U" component={HomePage}/>
```